# Creating event for Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Here is a link to, how to create event in Microsoft Word.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/objects-properties-methods/using-events-with-the-application-object-word

I created my own class module, and my own code in procedure.

When I try `Set X.App = Word.Application`

I get

> Run-time error '424' Object required

X is declared in `dim` before `App` is declared in class module.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @barneyos My code and error reference (screenshot) https://c2n.me/44KAaqA

Comment: Rename your class module with name "EventClassModule" and try again.

Comment: Also Sub App_DocumentChange() should be placed in class module, not in Module1.

Comment: @barneyos, there is some problem, code is not erroneus, but calling ```Module1.Register_Event_Handler``` does nothing, calling ```EventClassModule.App_DocumentChange``` is not a valid call, and real document change do not raise messageBox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class module code write this:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_DocumentChange()
    MsgBox "App_DocumentChange - active document has been changed."
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    MsgBox "Class Initialize"
End Sub
```

Name this class module as EventClassModule

In your Module1 code write:

```
Dim X As New EventClassModule
Sub Register_Event_Handler()
    Set X.App = Application
End Sub
```

Now, if you run sub Register_Event_Handler you should see messagebox "Class Initialize". Note that App_DocumentChange event occurs when you change active document for other, not when you change the content of active document.

Comment: may you explain what does "occurs when you change active document for other" it mean

Comment: [Occurs when a new document is created, when an existing document is opened, or when another document is made the active document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.documentchange)

Comment: it seems I need to run register function every time if I close my doc and open again, is it possible to register event handler for this document to be valid, if I open document tomorrow?

Comment: You may call this sub every time you open this document. Just add in ThisDocument module following code  `Private Sub Document_Open()  Register_Event_Handler  End Sub`